# Inner join vs all of the similar data in the different tables

Tags: sql, database, datatable, inner-join, difference

Which of the following database patterns would be a better model

For example:

```
Teacher(id, name, surname, login,password, subject, degree....)

Student(id, name, surname, login, password, group, faculty....)
```

VS

```
User(id, login, password, name, surname)

Student(id, group, faculty...)

Teacher(id, object, degree...)
```

And join it by inner join?

Which way would be preferred?

Comment: Since some students may also teach, I'd go with alternative 2.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284)

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends.  In the first model, `students` and `teachers` are separate entities, entirely.  So, relationships are to one of them but not to the other.

In the second model, `students` and `teachers` are subsets of `users` (presumably, the `id`s are the same in the three tables).  This allows you to have other tables that reference `users` -- say an address table or a transaction table.

It is not clear if your data model needs relationships to `users`.  So, there is no way to say that one is "better" than the other.